# assert_select not working after redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, functional-testing

Can an `assert_select` work after an `assert_redirected_to`? I have the following controller action and I'm getting a failure.

```
test "get switchboard" do
  ...
  assert_redirected_to employees_url # success
  assert_select 'div' # fail
end
```

Comment: This does not answer your question, but I would try to have just one assert there. If the redirect_to assert failed, the select one would not be reported...

Comment: @Nobita As shown in the comments, the `redirected_to` assert passes. It also passed before I added in the `assert_select`.

Comment: I know, I read that. It is just a suggestion for trying to have just one assert per test. Imagine that the redirected_to failed. You would never know if the select one would fail or not.

Comment: I believe putting `follow_redirect!` after the `assert_redirected_to` line might help... I thought I should mention it in case someone else has this question.

Comment: ... the `assert_redirected_to` goes after whatever redirect happened ... that's why the makers of rails put a "ed" ending on the word...to help it make more sense.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/ResponseAssertions.html

Answer (score 3):

This question is old, but I'll go ahead and answer it since I ran into a similar problem. `assert_select` can work after a redirect, but you must first tell the test to "follow" the redirect. So, in your case, you could do something like this:

```
test "get switchboard" do
  ...
  assert_redirected_to employees_url # redirected, not "success" per se
  follow_redirect!                   # this is what you need to do
  assert_response :success           # if you still want to...
  assert_select 'div'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`assert_select` works just as its described in the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select).

I assume that you are trying to do the `assert_select` on some element on the page that you are redirecting to. The problem with this is that that redirected route is actually not getting rendered.

The first thing that I would do if I were you is toss a `binding.pry` right in front of that `assert_select` and take a look at the `response.body` which will reveal what is actually being rendered. My guess is that you will see something like :

```
<html><body>You are being <a href=\"https://bigoldtest.net/as/1/oauth_provider_credentials?response_code=success\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"
```

rather than actual page that you is going to be redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is stated above in the comments:

add `follow_redirect!` after `assert_redirected_to` and your assert_select statements will pass

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).